# Get list of event receiver using powershell for sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, remote-event-receiver

I need to verify if a remote event receiver is well attached on a list ,can you show me the code for powershell for sharepoint online.

Comment: Have you tried the PnP Powershell: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_powershell/getpnpeventreceiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Keshav please check out the following [link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Get-all-event-receivers-on-479a1e8d).
Make sure you have Installed SharePoint Online SDK.

Comment: The link is dead. Archived version is at https://web.archive.org/web/20200318054833/https:/gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Get-all-event-receivers-on-479a1e8d